# Not able to bind dropdownlist values coming from json values from databases in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I want to bind control values based on the data from the `database table`. All the controls like textbox are getting bind except the dropdownlist values are not getting bind.

Below is my code

```js
function BindDataTableToJSONProject(strVal) {

            var ProjectData = JSON.parse(strVal);

            var getJSONValue = ProjectData.Table[0];
            if (getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME != "" && getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME != null) {
                $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProjMan').val(getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlProjMan" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProjMan" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">ABC</option>
    <option value="2">PQR</option>
    <option value="3">XYZ</option>
</select>
```

Below is my json data for the same.

`{ID: 6, MST_ID: 107, PROJECT_NO: "R4G-25-APD-210", CR_NO: "R4G-25-APD-ACR-1212", APPLICATION_NAME: "Workflow for VSAT Application", PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME: "XYZ",  …}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be looping through `options` inside select tag  and then checking if the `.text()` is equal to `PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME` if yes then add `selected` true to that option.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var getJSONValue = {
  "ID": 6,
  "MST_ID": 107,
  "PROJECT_NO": "R4G-25-APD-210",
  "CR_NO": "R4G-25-APD-ACR-1212",
  "APPLICATION_NAME": "Workflow for VSAT Application",
  "PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME": "XYZ"
}
BindDataTableToJSONProject();

function BindDataTableToJSONProject() {
  if (getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME != "" && getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME != null) {
    //loop through option
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProjMan option').each(function() {
      //get text of option check if equal to pmn
      if ($(this).text() == getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME) {
        $(this).prop("selected", true) //set slectd true
      }
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlProjMan" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProjMan" class="form-control">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">ABC</option>
  <option value="2">PQR</option>
  <option value="3">XYZ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hey Swati, thanks for the answer.. that did the trick..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You try to set value (that is `3`) `<option value="3">XYZ</option>`

but you select the parameter of the text  `getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME == "XYZ"`

Comment: when I try with `$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlProjMan').text(getJSONValue.PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME);` the whole dropdown list gets clear.!!

Comment: because the `.text` is change the full text of drop down list box

Comment: @hub I am looking for, usually I know the value - its not so easy from what I see

Comment: @hud here is what they do : https://www.codespeedy.com/select-option-from-dropdown-by-text-in-jquery/

Comment: @hud I think that you must find some other better solution to get know the value on select - to send the value on jSon data

Comment: see the above answer given by swati..!! is that ok to go ?

Comment: @hud looks fine